# Javascript equivalent for the technique called behind editors like Nodes Editor of Blender

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodes, blender

I need to know how this type of dynamic connections is called between the "nodes":

[image: Blender node editor]

<sub>Image source: https://orange.blender.org/wp-content/themes/orange/images/blog/noodles.jpg</sub>

Also does someone know a javascript library for generating these nodes with connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "Directed Acyclic Graph". You should have a look at the [Raphaël Library](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/). Especially this [example](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/graffle.html).